# Connect SOAP Api with VPN in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I want to connect a SOAP API in my php program, that needs to be hit by using VPN as specified in their below mentioned API documentation.

**API Documentation**

> Link will be active as under:
>
> http://10.0.1.00
>
> To connect the above link use following VPN tunnel:
>
> Host: 202.70.00.000
>
> UserID: ExampleConnect
>
> Password: ExampleConnect@786
>
> **"Sample endpoint can be found below."**

**End Point & Parameters**

> http://[SERVER_IP]/PowerSuite/PSXMLSearch.asmx?wsdl
>
> 6.1  **PSXML_SEARCH_SUPP** - The main entry point and the authentication information.
>
> | Element | Description | Type | Length |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | MSGID | Message ID (Unique identifier of the message) | String | 32 |
> | USERID | User ID for authentication | String | 10 |
> | PASSWORD | Password for authentication | String | 20 |
> | OPTION | ALL – Default , LIKE – Partial match , EXACT – Exact match | String | 5 |
> | SUPPNO | Supplier number to search for: You can enter the first few characters only if the search option is LIKE. | String | 12 |
> | SUPPNAME | Supplier name to search for: You can enter the first few characters only if the search option is LIKE. | String | 120 |

**My PHP Code**

So i tried following code using proxy parameters for SOAP client.

But it keep showing me error.

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "http://10.0.1.00/PowerSuite/PSXMLSearch.asmx?wsdl";
    $params = array(
      'MSGID'   =>  "TRAVEK_EBOOK001",
      'USERID'  =>  "ExampleConnect",
      'PASSWORD' => "ExampleConnect@786",
      'OPTION'  =>  'ALL'
    ); 

  try {
      $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl,array(
                    'proxy_host'     => "202.70.00.000",
                    'proxy_login'    => "ExampleConnect",
                    'proxy_password' => "ExampleConnect@786"
              ));
      $data = $soap->PSXMLSearchSupplier($params);
        echo "<pre>"; 
        print_r($data); 
        echo "</pre>";
    
      die();                    
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
      $e->getMessage();
      var_dump($e->getMessage());
      die();
  }
```

?>

**I am looking for an expert advise** that, either i am doing some thing wrong or that was from API.

Comment: You have to follow the instructions of VPN. They are like download xxx VPN client imprt file or fill the form with your credentials. Then your program can connect to server and get data

Comment: how about Guzzle?

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#proxy